# Unity - Rotate Game Object on Swipe / drag gesture regards the camera pan / rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, rotation

So I have tried many script found online and also try to tweak free asset like lean touch in unity.

But I could not find the best fit for my project.

What I want to achieve is ability to rotate a game object in all axis (x, y, z) regarding the camera position / rotation.

The camera will always focus on the game object and rotate around the game object.

So whenever the camera rotate on specific angle I would like to detect that any drag / swipe gesture (x swipe, or y swipe) on screen will rotate the game object on the specific axis (x, y, z) that Perpendicular to the swipe / drag gesture.

Please advice
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do for this is using your cameras orientation and do e.g.

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
        targetTransform.Rotate(cameraTransform.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * multiplier, Space.World);
        targetTransform.Rotate(cameraTransform.up * touch.deltaPosition.y * multiplier, Space.World);
    }
}
```

---

**Update**

As you said you actually only want one axis so the one with the bigger swipe movement you could so something like e.g.

```
if(touch.deltaPosition.x > touch.deltaPosition.y)
{ 
    targetTransform.Rotate(cameraTransform.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * multiplier, Space.World); 
} 
else 
{
     targetTransform.Rotate(cameraTransform.up * touch.deltaPosition.y * multiplier, Space.World); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll try this

Comment: Thanks, I have tried it and I don't think this fit my project. The script will rotate game object in any direction on regard the camera axis. But What my project want to achieve is how is it possible to detect if the swipe direction is perpendicular to one of the game object's axis whether it is X, Y, Z axis of the game object then rotate the game object on that one specific axis. Thanks

Comment: Oh I see .. in that case simply check `if(touch.deltaPosition.x > touch.deltaPosition.y) { targetTransform.Rotate(cameraTransform.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * multiplier, Space.World); } else {targetTransform.Rotate(cameraTransform.up * touch.deltaPosition.y * multiplier, Space.World); }` ;)

Comment: @derHugo Hey! How do I use your solution for the new input system?